# javascript time ticker

Tags: javascript, date, time, ticker

I want to build a simple time ticker.

Basically I will have a global javascript variable injected from the server side that will represent in my business model a active task start time for an agent.

I want to show in a  tag the digital time format between that global that date and now, but the issue I have is with the milliseconds from the difference between those 2 dates.

I have created a JSFiddle but the difference between new Date() and that specific date is not showing properly.

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/alexpeta/ZmzDh/3/

Can you guys spot the bug or the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d.toLocaleString()` might have a word with you ;) tip: no, you are not measuring time since September 22, you are measuring time to October 22.

http://jsfiddle.net/LDKh7/

Comment: Man, do i need a pair of glasses lol! Indeed, it was october and now its showing ok in your fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmzDh/1/)

Replace:

```
var t = setInterval('tick()',1000);
```

with:

```
var t = setInterval(tick,1000);
```

It's always a good idea to use function reference and not a string in `setInterval`

Comment: ah great! now its working on jsfiddle. thank you sir. now the question remains: why is it showing like 19 hours lol. the transformMiliseconds() function works, if you give it like 3600000  it will indeed show 01:00:00 hours so its fine.

Comment: yes it is functional, the span contains the desired format, but for my browser and regional settings ( Romania time)  now its 17:37(5 o'clock) and the start time is 13:00 (1 o'clock), so the display should say 4 hours. is it ok for you?

Comment: Yeah, i'm around 2.5 hours from that time and it's showing the correct time span

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
  TargetDate = "12/31/2020 5:00 AM";
  BackColor = "palegreen";                   
  ForeColor = "navy";                    
  CountActive = true;                   
  CountStepper = -1;                 
  LeadingZero = true;                            
  DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%%   Seconds.";                      
  FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";                  
   </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js"></script>
```

Comment: Be sure to offer some sort of explanation along with your code.